# are static variable in a class duplicated when a new instance of the class is created?

Tags: java, oop

Here there. Suppose i have this class

```
public class EpicClass{
    public static ArrayList<String> arylst = new ArrayList<>();

    public String field1;
    public String field2:
}
```

Now if I execute this code:

```
/* ... Code which adds stuff to arylst ... */
EpicClass foo = new EpicClass();
EpicClass bar = new EpicClass();
```

Will the stuff in the ArrayList be duplicated in `foo` and `bar`??

Comment: How *are* static variables access from *outside* the class (or without any instance of said class)? What does this indicate about how static fields operate "between" instances?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Static variables are allocated once, when the class is initialized. From the [Java Language Specification, §8.3.1.1 `static` fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1):

> If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized ([§12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)).

Note that this refers to the field itself, not to any value the field may contain. Unless the field is declared `final`, you can assign values one after another to it. In particular, you can [mis]use constructors to assign a value to the field every time an instance is created. In general, you should avoid assigning to a static field in a constructor. (There are exceptions, such as using a static field to count instance object creations.)

You can access a static field using the class name or using a reference to an instance.<sup>1</sup> Thus, the following are all equivalent (provided `foo` and `bar` are of type `EpicClass`):

```
EpicClass.arylst
foo.arylst
bar.arylst
```

(Accessing a static field via an instance reference is considered wrong and will usually generate a compiler warning, but it works perfectly well—even if the reference is `null`, because the compiler converts it to the first form.) In that sense only, the "stuff in the ArrayList" will appear to be duplicated in each instance of the class. However, there is only one instance of the `ArrayList` and you are just accessing it via (seemingly) different mechanisms.

<sup>1</sup><sub>provided the field is accessible at all, of course.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

No, There is only a single piece of storage for a static variables whether it's preemptive type or Object type, regardless of how many object are created. even static data initialization happen only once.
      i can give example which prove that this concept. i am making small modification in your above program. in place of 'arylst' i am initializing my custom object.

```
class Book {
    Book(String s) {
        System.out.println("Book(" + s + ")");
    }
}

class EpicClass {
    public static Book book = new Book("static");
    public Book book1 = new Book("non-static");

    public String field1;
    public String field2;
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EpicClass foo = new EpicClass();
        EpicClass bar = new EpicClass();
    }

}
```

and output prove that the above concept.

O/P :

```
Book(static)
Book(non-static)
Book(non-static)
```

EpicClass Object created 2 times ( 'foo' and 'bar' ). but this class static variable book initialize only once. but non static variable book1 initialize 2 times ( for both 'foo' and 'bar' ). it means static variables shared by all the instances but all instances have own copy of non-static variables.

Answer (score 1):

No, because `foo` and `bar` **don't even have an ArrayList**<sup>[1]</sup>. It's static, which means it belongs to the class, so you access it like this:

```
EpicClass.arylst.add("test"); // or do whatever you want
```

<sup>[1] well, technically you can do `foo.arylst`, but you shouldn't; that's misusing static memebers, and it will give you a warning as well</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No, that is the whole point of static variables. They exist on a class level instead of an instance level, so the instances does not contain an own "copy" of the data member.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `EpicClass.arylst` or `foo.arylst` or `bar.arylst` . They all point same object. ArrayList itself is one and only one in `EpicClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Static variable will internalized once and Only one shared memory allocated to all the instance of the class. 
static variable are class variables and its not specific to any instance. Simply we can say its common for all the instance of the class. Whenever changed the static values from one instance of the class that modified value is visible to all other instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Running the following code will print `Hi`

```
EpicClass foo = new EpicClass();
EpicClass bar = new EpicClass();

foo.arylst.add("Hi");
for(int i = 0; i<bar.arylst.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(bar.arylst.get(i));
}
```

So as the others said - a static variabel is declared once, and belongs to the class. Modifying a static mutable object in once instance of a class will, modify it in all other instances as well, since the static object belongs to the *class* and not the instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

No. Static variables will not be created every time when you create a new instance of the class. Plus it also holds the same value for all the instances. (If you have created more than one instance) .

We can also say that ***“Static variables don't change/represent the state of an object”***.
Kindly correct me if I'm wrong here.